# Get telegram user status with telethon

Tags: python, telegram, status, telethon

im trying to create a python script that checks wether the user is online or not.
I succeed making a season between Telegram and python using telethon but Im really having a bad time getting the correct syntax to get one of my contacts status.
Any help will be appricated !

```
from telethon.tl.types import UserStatusOnline, UserStatusOffline, ContactStatus
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from datetime import datetime

### Client Side ###
phone = "+"
api_id = 
api_hash = ""
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
else:
    print("Logging Complete")

account = client.get_entity('chats_name')
if isinstance(account.status, UserStatusOffline):
    if contact.online != False:
        contact.online = False
        event.respond(f'{utc2localtime(account.status.was_online).strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)}: {contact.name} went offline.')
    elif contact.last_offline != account.status.was_online:
        if contact.last_offline is not None:
            event.respond(f'{utc2localtime(account.status.was_online).strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)}: {contact.name} went offline after being online for short time.')
        else:
            event.respond(f'{utc2localtime(account.status.was_online).strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)}: {contact.name} went offline.')
            contact.last_offline = account.status.was_online
    elif isinstance(account.status, UserStatusOnline):
            if contact.online != True:
                contact.online = True
                event.respond(f'{datetime.now().strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)}: {contact.name} went online.')   
            else:
                if contact.online != False:
                    contact.online = False
                    event.respond(f'{datetime.now().strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)}: {contact.name} went offline.')
                    contact.last_offline = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the [`User`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/user.html) object of whoever you're interested in and then check the type of the [`status`](https://tl.telethon.dev/types/user_status.html) field to determine if they're online or not with [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

You can get the `User` in many ways: through the list of conversations you have ([`iter_dialogs`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.iter_dialogs)), fetching them by integer ID or string phone number ([`get_entity`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.users.UserMethods.get_entity)), or when you receive a message from them ([working with updates](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html)). All the methods in the documentation have examples, but you're encouraged to read it from the beginning to learn how to use the library.

Comment: Yeah bro i've looked deeper and found the entity but dont really know how to use it ..
It doesnt really matters to me how to get the user as long as it works..
I was trying everything and failed ..
Would u mind please helping me a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use events.UserUpdate for this something like:

```
@client.on(events.UserUpdate)
async def user_update_event_handler(event):
    if event.online:
        try:
            user_details = await client.get_entity(event.user_id)
            print(f" {user_details.first_name}, came online at : {datetime.now()}")
        except:
            print(event)
```

[Here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/events.html) you can find more details on events.